# How does "return render(request, 'path/path')" works in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Please explain how "return render(request, 'path/path')" this works step by step in any particular views.py file in django.

MYcode: (views.py)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoForm
from . import forms

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):
    registered=False
    if request.method=="POST":
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        user_form=UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if profile_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():

            user=user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False) 
            profile.user=user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered=True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()


    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',
                    {'user_form':user_form,
                    'profile_form':profile_form,
                    'registered':registered})
```

Code: (registration.html)

```
{% extends "basic_app/basic.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}

<div class="jumbotron">
  {% if registered %}
  <h1>Thank you for registering!</h1>
  {% else %}
  <h1>Register Here!</h1>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

    {{user_form.as_p}}
    {{profile_form.as_p}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
  </form>
  {% endif %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

ALSO EXPLAIN: How the dictionary defined in "return" statement in views.py works step by step.

Comment: Please read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django web applications typically group the code that handles each of these steps into separate files:
[image]

**URLs:** While it is possible to process requests from every single URL via a single function, it is much more maintainable to write a separate view function to handle each resource. A URL mapper is used to redirect HTTP requests to the appropriate view based on the request URL. The URL mapper can also match particular patterns of strings or digits that appear in an URL, and pass these to a view function as data.

**View:** A view is a request handler function, which receives HTTP requests and returns HTTP responses. Views access the data needed to satisfy requests via models and delegate the formatting of the response to templates.

**Models:** Models are Python objects that define the structure of an application's data and provide mechanisms to manage (add, modify, delete) and query records in the database.

**Templates:** A template is a text file defining the structure or layout of a file (such as an HTML page), with placeholders used to represent actual content. A view can dynamically create an HTML page using an HTML template, populating it with data from a model. A template can be used to define the structure of any type of file; it doesn't have to be HTML!

***Here are `return render()` working process:***

```
return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',
                {'user_form':user_form,
                'profile_form':profile_form,
                'registered':registered})
```

This function uses the render() function to create the HttpResponse that is sent back to the browser. This function is a shortcut; it creates an HTML file by combining a specified HTML template and some data to insert in the template (provided in the variable named "context"). In the next section, we show how the template has the data inserted in it to create the HTML.

Follow the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Introduction) for more details.